# Android How to play multiple selected files from external via TextToSpeech?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

My requirement is, select txt files from my SDCard and then read those files and play that files contains via TextToSpeech.

Here I have multiple files selection and I want to play all files one after another via TextToSpeech.

I surfed on Google for this but unable to find way to speak multiple files, please share any idea for the same and also I would like to understand `synthesizeToFile()` method with example as I searched but still not clear.

Please do needful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your text file to a string. Use readFileToString from Apache common io is the easiest. Then you have to synthesize the string and read MediaPlayer since TTS speak will not start while there are files that are synthesized. When initialize the TTS you need to set setOnUtteranceCompletedListener or setOnUtteranceProgressListener.
It will be slow for the first text to be read since the synthesize will take time. The code below should be running from a different thread then the code to play the file using media player.

```
for (File file : listOfFilesToBeRead) {
    String text = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
    HashMap<String, String> myHashRender = new HashMap<String, String>();
    myHashRender.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, an_id_for_example_filename_of_file_above);
    mTts.synthesizeToFile(text, myHashRender, filenameWithpath_to_save_the_synthesized_file);
}
```

Then `OnUtteranceCompletedListener` or `UtteranceProgressListener` use MediaPlayer to play the file with path utteranceId.

Comment: Also, you must check that request text is under 4000 characters. If it is over, TextToSpeech will not synthesize.

Comment: @Kae10 you are right I normally split the file to synthesize into 500 characters so I forgot about the limit.

Comment: @HoanNguyen thank you for sharing, here my setOnUtteranceProgressListener is not called. How can I identify that my current file is completed.

Comment: Did you set the OnUtteranceProgressListener when initialize the TTS? If I do not remember wrong then with the code I posted in the answer onStart and onDone will be called.